# NSJSONSerialization not creating mutable containers

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

Here's the code:

```
NSError *parseError;
NSMutableArray *listOfObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[@"[]" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
NSLog(@"Is mutable? %li", [listOfObjects isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]);

listOfObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[@"[[],{}]" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
NSLog(@"Is mutable? %li", [listOfObjects isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]);
```

As you can see, I'm calling exactly the same method for parsing the JSON both times, one with an empty list in the JSON, and then a list with an object inside. Here's the result:

```
Is mutable? 0
Is mutable? 1
```

The problem is that the NSJSONSerialization doesn't seem to follow the option to create mutable containers for empty lists. Seems like a bug to me, but maybe I just misunderstanding things.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure they are not coming out as NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: What's the output when you run `po [[listOfObjects class] superclass]` in the debug console?

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Mac OS X 10.7 – only empty arrays seem to be affected. It seems to be fixed in 10.8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works just as expected:

```
NSString *s = @"{ \"objs\": [ \"a\", \"b\" ] }";    
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:[s UTF8String] length:[s length]];
id dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

NSLog(@"%@", dict);

[[dict objectForKey:@"objs"] addObject:@"c"];

NSLog(@"%@", dict);
NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"objs"] class]);
```

Here's the console output:

```
2012-03-28 13:49:46.224 ExampleRunner[42526:707] {
    objs =     (
        a,
        b
    );
}
2012-03-28 13:49:46.225 ExampleRunner[42526:707] {
    objs =     (
        a,
        b,
        c
    );
}
2012-03-28 13:49:46.225 ExampleRunner[42526:707] __NSArrayM
```

**EDIT**

Note that if we append the following line to the code above...

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"objs"] superclass]);
```

...we get the following output on the console:

```
2012-03-28 18:09:53.770 ExampleRunner[42830:707] NSMutableArray
```

...just in case it wasn't clear that `__NSArrayM` is a private subclass of `NSMutableArray`, thus proving that the OP's code did indeed work as expected (except for his `NSLog` statement).

**EDIT**

Oh, and by the way, the following line of code...

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[dict objectForKey:@"objs"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]);
```

...results in the following console output:

```
2012-03-28 18:19:19.721 ExampleRunner[42886:707] 1
```

**EDIT (responding to changed question)**

Interesting...looks like a bug. Given the following code:

```
NSData *dictData2 = [@"{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id dict2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dictData2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", [dict2 class]);
NSLog(@"%@", [dict2 superclass]);
NSLog(@"%d", [dict2 isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]);

// This works...
[dict2 setObject:@"quux" forKey:@"baz"];
NSLog(@"%@", dict2);

NSData *dictData = [@"{}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id emptyDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dictData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", [emptyDict class]);
NSLog(@"%@", [emptyDict superclass]);
NSLog(@"%d", [emptyDict isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]);

//...but this fails:
[emptyDict setObject:@"quux" forKey:@"baz"];
NSLog(@"%@", emptyDict);
```

Here's the console output:

```
2012-03-29 09:40:52.781 ExampleRunner[43816:707] NSMutableDictionary
2012-03-29 09:40:52.782 ExampleRunner[43816:707] 1
2012-03-29 09:40:52.782 ExampleRunner[43816:707] __NSCFDictionary
2012-03-29 09:40:52.782 ExampleRunner[43816:707] NSMutableDictionary
2012-03-29 09:40:52.783 ExampleRunner[43816:707] 1
2012-03-29 09:40:52.783 ExampleRunner[43816:707] {
    baz = quux;
    foo = bar;
}
2012-03-29 09:40:52.784 ExampleRunner[43816:707] __NSCFDictionary
2012-03-29 09:40:52.784 ExampleRunner[43816:707] NSMutableDictionary
2012-03-29 09:40:52.784 ExampleRunner[43816:707] 1
2012-03-29 09:40:52.785 ExampleRunner[43816:707] NSException: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

So empty arrays and dictionaries created this way don't seem to behave as expected.

Comment: The [expenses class] is still an NSArray though, instead of a mutable array, no?

Comment: Nope. First, you can't add an object to an instance of `NSArray`. Second, if you look at the console output, the array is actually an instance of `__NSArrayM`, which is a private subclass of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply so far.. I have updated the question though, I figured I was not explaining the problem correctly.. can you check again?

Answer (score 8):

Here's my workaround for this problem:

```
#import "NSJSONSerialization+MutableBugFix.h"

@implementation NSJSONSerialization (NSJSONSerialization_MutableBugFix)

+ (id)JSONObjectWithDataFixed:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error {
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:opt error:error];

    if (opt & NSJSONReadingMutableContainers) {
        return [self JSONMutableFixObject:object];
    }

    return object;
}

+ (id)JSONMutableFixObject:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // NSJSONSerialization creates an immutable container if it's empty (boo!!)
        if ([object count] == 0) {
            object = [object mutableCopy];
        }

        for (NSString *key in [object allKeys]) {
            [object setObject:[self JSONMutableFixObject:[object objectForKey:key]] forKey:key];
        }
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // NSJSONSerialization creates an immutable container if it's empty (boo!!)
        if (![object count] == 0) {
            object = [object mutableCopy];
        }

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [object count]; ++i) {
            [object replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[self JSONMutableFixObject:[object objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }
    }

    return object;
}

@end
```

So I call:

```
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithDataFixed:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Instead of the usual:

```
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Answer (score 1):

Others also take this for a bug, see

1. https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/issues/44 or
2. https://github.com/johnlabarge/jlbiosutils/blob/master/jlbiosutils/DynamicProperties.m, for example.

In the latter case you can see complete workaround also for empty dictionaries (see `DynamicGetter(...)` method).

Comment: Anything that Jens Alfke considers a bug is a bug to me. Thanks for the links, I ended up fixing this pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do:

```
BOOL needsWorkaround = YES;
if (needsWorkaround)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* appState2 = 
        (__bridge_transfer NSMutableDictionary*) 
        CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy (
            kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge void*)appState,
            kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
        );
    appState = appState2;
}
```