# Objective-C IOS Xcode: Unable to modify object in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

My problem is that I have a class property that is of type `NSMutableArray`, as defined in my header file, yet when I attempt to modify one of the array elements (an `NSDictionary`) I receive the following runtime error:

> 2013-01-16 14:17:20.993 debtaculous[5674:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent
>   to immutable object'

Header declaration:

```
//  BudgetViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BudgetViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
- (IBAction)afterTaxIncomeEditingDidEnd:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *budgetArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *afterTaxIncome;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *budgetTableView;

@end
```

Method that generates the error:

```
-(void)applyCCCSWeights
{
    NSMutableDictionary *valueDict;
    NSString *newAmount;

    for (id budgetElement in [self budgetArray]) {
        valueDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:budgetElement];
        newAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", [[self afterTaxIncome].text floatValue] * [[budgetElement objectForKey:@"cccs_weight"] floatValue]];
        [valueDict setValue:newAmount forKeyPath:@"amount"];

        [[self budgetArray] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:valueDict];
        NSLog(@"%0.2f (%0.2f)", [[budgetElement objectForKey:@"amount"] floatValue], [[self afterTaxIncome].text floatValue] * [[budgetElement objectForKey:@"cccs_weight"] floatValue]);
    }

    [self.budgetTableView reloadData];
}
```

// Note the `replaceObjectAtIndex:0` above is just a placeholder. This will be replaced with the correct index.

Comment: Where do you init your array?

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize budgetArray

Comment: Main parts:

    [self setUrlData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]];
    [self setBudgetArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[self urlData] options:kNilOptions error:&error]];

Comment: There you go... Look at the options in NSJSONSerialization. Use one that creates mutable arrays and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your init method, put this:

```
budgetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Also, why not use dictionary and array literal syntax?

```
-(void)applyCCCSWeights {
    NSMutableDictionary *valueDict;
    NSString *newAmount;

    for (NSDictionary *budgetElement in [self budgetArray]) {
        valueDict = [budgetElement mutableCopy];
        newAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", [[self afterTaxIncome].text floatValue] * [budgetElement[@"cccs_weight"] floatValue]];
        valueDict[@"amount"] = newAmount;

        _budgetArray[0] = valueDict;
        NSLog(@"%0.2f (%0.2f)", [budgetElement[@"amount"] floatValue], [[self afterTaxIncome].text floatValue] * [budgetElement[@"cccs_weight"] floatValue]);
    }

    [self.budgetTableView reloadData];
}
```

Notice that `[[self budgetArray] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:valueDict];`

becomes: `_budgetArray[0] = valueDict;`

Comment: Thanks all for the help.  My final solution was to use the above method and a local "NSMutableArray *tempArray" to hold the new values and finally:

self.budgetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];
[self.budgetTableView reloadData];

Comment: See comment above. Read the NSJSONSerialization documentation.

Answer (score 4):

`budgetArray` is surely immutable, you have to create it mutable.

Probably you're doing something like this:

```
budgetArray= [NSArray arraWithObjects; obj1, obj2, nil];
```

And ignoring the compiler warning. Make it mutable:

```
budgetArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I found a related Question that may be the root of the issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912707/nsjsonserialization-not-creating-mutable-containers

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain you cannot change a mutable object during enumeration.

This SO question may help: [Setting an object during fast enumeration problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693892/setting-an-object-during-fast-enumeration-problems)

Comment: You're right but that isn't the exception he is receiving. So +1 for predicting his next SO question after he listens to @Ramy

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an array while doing a fast iteration over the array. On the other hand, it's entirely unnecessary; the code is absolutely inefficient: Just make the elements of the array NSMutableDictionaries, then change the dictionaries directly, instead of creating a copy and then changing an element in the copy.

Noticed later that you use NSJSONSerialization; look at the flags and don't pass 0 blindly.